# Will there be quantum to digital converters in the same way we need digital to analog converters to communicate between the 2 mediums?

Tags: applications

I know this forum is for more technical questions...

As my interest is in music, I was thinking about the nature of analog and digital mediums. And I just thought, for some reason, we have 'Quantum Home Computers', (which I don't know if happens) would we have to encode all existing audio formats? And if for some reason we couldn't, would we need a quantum to digital to analog converter? How would sound work on Quantum Computers?

Dumb questions, I don't want to waste any of your time with, but how would audio work on quantum computers as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

First of all we have to solve a problem with storing information in a quantum form. Currently, researches work on so-called quantum RAM (qRAM) to allow a quantum computer have a bigger memory than registers in a quantum processor. Details are discussed here: [Quantum Random Access Memory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.1879.pdf). This would expand capabilities of quantum computers and make them more similar to classical computers in terms of architecture.

When the issue with storing a data will be solved, we can start to think how to encode an audio data in a quantum form and how to operate with them. Of course, there will have to be a converters from a quantum data to classical ones in order to use them for playing sounds (or showing pictures on screen etc). So, you are right, a converter similar to A/D and D/A converters would be needed.

If you are interested in using quantum computers for audio processing, you would like this book: [Mastering Quantum Computing with IBM QX: Explore the world of quantum computing using the Quantum Composer and Qiskit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G8PHHRZ). There is a chapter dealing with using a quantum computer for producing tones via MIDI.